# How can I directly add properties from a Spring Boot property source to the environment

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot property source file containing a set of arbitrary properties. I would like to get all of those properties and add them to the environment.

I tried injecting the Environment into the class, and I am able to use that to get known properties. But I am not sure how to get *all* properties from there.'

If course I can use a traditional Properties.load() but is there a Spring way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [@PropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) anotation?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using `PropertySource` because you can't configure the precedence of the properties that you add. You may want that these properties can be overridden in some way, maybe? Or you may want that these properties take precedence over others. For this, I recommend  you implement an `EnvironmentPostProcessor`.

There is a sample in this [university session at Devoxx](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uof5h-j0IeE) where [we showcase how to read a file from the home directory](https://youtu.be/uof5h-j0IeE?t=1h17m46s) and add it after command line properties. You could do pretty much the same thing and order them the way you want.

The sample app is [available here](https://github.com/snicoll-demos/hello-service-auto-configuration) if you want to give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your properties into the "application.properties" (or any of the other places described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)), the properties are automatically available in Spring's Environment.

One way to access the properties then is simply to `@Autowire` the `Environment` into the class where you want to access it.